# Почему не срабатывает поиск по регулярному выражению (sql oracle)

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle

Нужно найти строку, которая начинаются на `17` и оканчивается на `ST`.

Вот эта строка:

```
17 S MILLER ST
```

Мой код:

```
    Select 
         addr1
    from 
         contact
    where 
        REGEXP_LIKE (addr1, '^17[\w ]*ST$')
```

Почему SQL Developer не ищет эту строку. Хоть ресурс  `regex101.com` показывает, что регулярное выражение правильное?

Comment: нет в  SQL Developer такое (двойная слэш) не прошло

Comment: а такой `'^17[[:alnum:] ]*ST$'` не сработает?

Comment: Андрей, спасибо большое. Сработало)